# Xcode 8 beta 4 Constraint/Layout mismatch

Tags: ios, autolayout

i noticed a strange behavior since the latest Xcode 8 beta 4. All constraints got calculated correctly, but are not represented correctly in layout. it's a little difficult to explain it. as you can see in the image below. the constraint has the correct size (72px), still the actual view has only a width of 28.5.

Just wanted to know if someone did also encounter this and whether constraint calculation/setup has changed for beta 4!?

thanks for the input in advance :)

[image: calculations]

*UPDATE*

It seems that only views/constraints inside UITableViewCells are affected.

Comment: Can you please file a bug at bugreport.apple.com and attach your sample project? We'd like to investigate this.

Comment: I have this issue to on my view controllers. Everything shows up just right on the preview with Xcode 8 beta 3, but when I upgraded the beta 4, everything got messed up. On the preview, it looks like something's messed up on every view because they don't match anymore. Oh, and I filed a radar

Comment: @Quinn Taylor: I will. I already created a very simple project with a couple of views where i couldn't reproduce this. That's why i suspect that it only happens (for me) in UITableViewController. I will try to recreate it and submit a bug.

Comment: Maybe the view hasn't laid itself out yet, which is why constraint value and frame / bounds don't match.

Comment: I don't know, but it was fixed the next beta without me having to change anything :)